# I am a creature from the ancient world

Tags: riddle

My head has two faces.
My upper body is powerful.
My belt honors two great men.
My legs and feet are numbered incorrectly.

What am I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may be the

> months of the year.

My head has two faces.

> January is named after Janus, the Roman god of beginnings and transitions who is depicted with two faces.

My upper body is powerful.

> March is named after Mars, the mighty Roman god of war.

My belt honors two great men.

> July and August are named after Julius Caesar and the Emperor Augustus.

My legs and feet are numbered incorrectly.

> September, October, November and December were named as such as they were originally the seventh to tenth months of the year.

Comment: Superb answer @Tom

Comment: I think "the calendar" would be more appropriate, as creature is singular :)